# Include code in method of class C# out of class

Tags: c#

Already an hours sitting on the code, I think nothing. Tired.

I have a class:

```
class ConnectionThread
        {
            public TcpListener threadListener;

            public ConnectionThread(TcpListener lis)
            {
                threadListener = lis;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleConnection));

            }

            public void HandleConnection(object state)
            {

                TcpClient client = threadListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[25600000];
                String data = null;

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // I WANT INCLUDE HERE CODE OUT OF CLASS!!!
                }
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
        }
```

If my class in additional file, how is better way to include code in while cycle?
For example include this in while:

```
                data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                MessageBox.Show("Received: " + data);

                data = data.ToUpper();

                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);

                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                MessageBox.Show("Sent: " + data);
```

Comment: Use a method? If you want the code to sit in another class, use a static method or i.e. pass the stream in the constructor. But then better put the whole stream handling (including the while) into another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There are several overloads with different parameters. An alternative is solving the by making the class abstract and define the behavior in the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include an external file like you can in, for example, C++.

You have partial classes and partial methods, but you cannot directly include code segments.
You could wrap your code in a static method and then pass the appropriate values as parameters. If you use the `[AggressiveInlining]` attribute, the code should be inlined, and you could get the effect of code inclusion.

For what you want to do, I think only copy-pasting will work.

Comment: I think extracting method and using it is better approach

Comment: Me too. I just think the question was about C++ style #include directives.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependancy injection.. like create an interface or abstract class where you declare a method signature.After you implement this interface in another class. After you end up with something like

```
 public interface IMyInterface
    {
      String DoSomething();

    }

    class B:IMyInterface
    {
      public String DoSomething()
      {
        return "11111";

      }
    }


    class A{
    private IMyInterface b; 

    public A(IMyInterface b)
    {
      b = this.b;
    }

   public String DoSomething2()
    {
      return b.DoSomething();
    }

    }
```

in main..

```
A a = new A(new B());
a.DoSomething2();
```

So instead of b you pass the class that implemented your interface or abstract class.
So the real logic is injected and can be easy replaced. And it's outside of your class!

Comment: Hope this is what you wanna comrade)

Comment: There's no need for all that extra code such as the interface. Just inject Func<string>

Comment: Func<string> is a pre built delegate that is a class inherited from the MultiCallable class. It might look cleaner in your code but in guts it's the same approach (even bigger in lines of code). Just for fun explore how delegates look in IL. Honestly in reality my code even cleaner).Again it's a  personal preference, but I am from the Java background and don't like Microsoft magic)

Comment: The no. 1 rule of writing good code is make it readable. Lots of code reinventing the wheel is more difficult to read than using the BCL delegate.